# Angular import json file based on condition

Tags: angular, angular5

I been searching for ways but couldn't find a way to go. I have 4-5 json files that have the same structure and all but different values. Based on a value stored in localStorage, i want to load the appropriate json. Currently, I load a file at the top:

```
import * as data_json from "../app_data_files/file.json";
```

I tried doing. For e.g. based on this condition, import file 1

```
if ( 1 ==1){
    import * as data_json from "../app_data_files/file1.json";
 }
```

but typescript complains an import statement can happen only in a module or namespace.

The value in the localstarge matches the file to load so I can't really predict. What I check for is simply if there is value. If not the default one on top that is loaded is going to be used. Hope that makes sense.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try using Dynamic Imports. const data_json = import("../app_data_files/file1.json");

Comment: Could you answer it @Indragith so I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using Dynamic Imports:

```
const data_json = import("../app_data_files/file1.json");
```

Note: Dynamic Import will return a promise. you can either use async/await or .then to get the json objects

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load your json configuration using HttpClient.

YOu can use the following method :

```js
let myConf:any;
this.http.get("your_config.json").subscribe(res=>{this.myConf=res})
```

Comment: Thanks Matrimv...that did occur to me but since the app was working already on a single import, I thought we would extend it instead.